# Difference between MouseClick and DoubleClick

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls, mouseclick-event

**`WPF, Shapes`**

I have a custom `Shape`, and try to implement `MouseClick` and `MouseDoubleClick` stuff on it.

By eg. I need to *open a information window* about MyShape OnClick and *select* it OnDoubleClick.

The stub is the following:

```
public class MyShape : Shape
{
    public Point Point1, Point2;

    public MyShape() : base() { }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return new LineGeometry(Point1, Point2); }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if (e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            // Open Informational Window
        }
        else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            // Select Item
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I doubleclick both `// Only do MouseClick` and `// Only do MouseDoubleClick` happens.

Is there any way to avoid this in WPF, .NET 4?

Comment: You're trying to create very counter-intuitive and unexpected behavior.  **Don't**.

Comment: @SLaks: discuss about with our clients.

Comment: You should select shapes on _single_ -click, then show properties on double-click.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that if your clients actually use the behavior they're asking for, they'll change their minds.

Comment: @SLaks: see my first remark. This is a technical discussion, not a commercial one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between first click and second click in double click I think there is a time around 50 and 400 millisecond, So the bellow code is not a best one but do the trick:

```
bool firstClicked = false;

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if (e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            firstClicked = true;
            Task tsk = new TaskFactory()
                            .StartNew(
                            () => 
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime);
                                    if (firstClicked)
                                    {
                                        // if you want to use `e`
                                        // e.Source
                                        // Open Informational Window
                                    }
                                        firstClicked = false;
                                    }
                                        );

                                }

        }
        else if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            firstClicked = false;
            // Select Item
        }
    }
```

Comment: @serhio, yes I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I once had this very same problem. I needed to detect double clicks, but clicks and double clicks should behave as separate events. Meaning, if a double click was fired, click should not fire (because each action had different and not compatible effects in the UI).

The "native" double click didn't work for me because click events fired whether a double click happened or not. Here's some sample code in Actionscript. I'm sure you'll be able to follow the (simple) logic to implement it in .net. Note that I'm hardcoding the double click time, as I couldn't get the system value for it from Actionscript. It's not ideal, but it's I compromise I had to make. You should use the time interval provided by the OS (or your runtime) instead, if it's available to you.

Hope it helps.

```
package {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Button extends Sprite {

        public function DCButton() {
            super();
            graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            graphics.endFill();
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick);
        }

        private var _clickCount:int = 0;
        private var _doubleClickInterval:int = 200;

        private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            _clickCount++;
            //  start the timer and when it completes, check the number of clicks
            //  based on this, dispatch either click or doubleClick events
            if(_clickCount == 1) {
                setTimeout(checkDoubleClick,_doubleClickInterval,e);
            }
            else
            {
                checkDoubleClick(e);
            }

        }   

        private function checkDoubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

            if(_clickCount == 0) return;

            var type:String;

            if(_clickCount == 1) {
                type="click";
            } else if(_clickCount > 1) {
                type="doubleClick";
            }

            trace(type);

            _clickCount = 0;
            //  dispatch the detected event here...

        }           
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every DoubleClick starts with a Click.

Comment: I need to select MyShape OnClick and open w information window on DoubleClick.

Comment: You can't tell the difference between them without predicting the future.

Comment: oh, come on... there is MouseDoubleClick event on controls, different from MouseDown one. When I select a file in Windows, I do it witha click, and open in with DoubleClick

Comment: @Serhio: And it will fire a Click, then a DoubleClick.  I don't see your point.

Comment: A double click is, by definition, two clicks. The first one fires OnClick, the second one fires OnDoubleClick. Like @SLaks said, you can't prevent the first click from firing OnClick without predicting the future.

Comment: ok, people... I ask otherwise: how do I do not open the window if the user DoubleClicks on the sape, but to open it only when user click on it.

Comment: there is a possibility, waiting the SystemDoubleClick time, but I thought in .NET 4 there should be something easier to code...

Comment: @Serhio: You need to use a time machine to predict whether the user will click again after the first click.

Comment: @serhio. I don't know how this works in WPF, but it seems it works just like in Actionscript. In that case, yes, double click is not of much use. You have to implement it yourself, listening for click events and detecting double clicks manually. It'd be nice if you could pass some kind of flag to prevent clicks from firing if the user double clicked.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: this is exactly what I trying to do: detect doubleClick manually.

Comment: @serhio. Ok, I'll paste some sample code. It's Actionscript, but I'm sure you'll be able to follow the logic (which is quite simple) and adapt it to C#.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try an attached behaviour?

[Try this link for an explanation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx)

Maybe you can aggregate the events...i think that is what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is: a) on single click (and only on single click) select item.  b) on double click open info window (but not select)  is this wrong?

Comment: @miguel, let's complicate a little. just Open Window onClick, and just select on doubleClick.

Comment: Ok, so I would suggest that, when you click you open the window (and de-select the item, if the selection is happening) and on double-click perform only the selection.  You could probably do this without attached behaviours as well...

Comment: @miguel wheh I click any selection is happening. Selection is happening on DoubleClick. When I doubleClick, if the Click happens, the windows is opened. I don't want Window on DoubleClick

Comment: sorry i still dont understand, can you step-by-step explain the desired behavior

Comment: Click=> Window; DoubleClick=> Selection. `No DoubleClick=> No Window`

Comment: then you would need to add some sort of time out to wait for the input, i guess...

Comment: so, wait to show the windo on click to make sure it is not a double-click